# C++ std::set<Vertex> iterator with custom Vertex class

Tags: c++, iterator

I am confused with implementing iterators for custom classes.  I'm trying to implement an iterator for std::set where my Vertex class is declared as:

```
class Vertex{                                                   
public:
    int i, j; 
    std::set<Vertex*> adj; //references to adjacent vertices

    Vertex();
    ~Vertex();
    //end constructors

    /** must overload for set<Vertex> to function */
    const bool operator < (const Vertex &o) const;

};//END class Vertex
```

But if I define

```
iterator<Vertex*> begin(){
    return iterator<Vertex*>( *this, 0 ); 
}
iterator>Vertex*> end(){ 
    return iterator<Vertex*>( *this, sizeof(Vertex) ); 
}
```

So that I can hopefully iterate like:

```
set<Vertex*>::iterator it;
    //for all vertices adjacent of cur
    for(it = cur.begin(); it != cur.end(); it++){
        //...
    }
```

And receive these errors:

```
In file included from Vertex.cc:8:0:
Vertex.h:50:22: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 5)
 std::iterator<Vertex*> begin();
                      ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algoba
se.h:65:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h
:61,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\set:60,
                 from Vertex.h:10,
                 from Vertex.cc:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator_base_types.h:118:12
: error: provided for 'template<class _Category, class _Tp, class _Distance, cla
ss _Pointer, class _Reference> struct std::iterator'
     struct iterator
            ^
In file included from Vertex.cc:8:0:
Vertex.h:50:31: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
 std::iterator<Vertex*> begin();
                               ^
Vertex.h:51:22: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 5)
 std::iterator<Vertex*> end();

<additional errors>

ss _Pointer, class _Reference> struct std::iterator'
     struct iterator
            ^
Vertex.cc:114:29: error: invalid use of 'this' in non-member function
  return iterator<Vertex*>( *this, 0 );
                             ^
Vertex.cc: At global scope:
Vertex.cc:116:1: error: invalid use of template-name 'std::iterator' without an
argument list
 iterator>Vertex*> end(){
 ^
Vertex.cc: In function 'int begin()':
Vertex.cc:115:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-typ
e]
 }
 ^
make: *** [Vertex.o] Error 1
```

I need help figuring out how to go about doing this; I've found most tutorials/links confusing as well.  Note: I'm not using C++11

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a type called `iterator` that you didn't define, and the compiler thinks you're using `std::iterator`, which isn't what you want. Did you mean to define a custom iterator type here?

Comment: `std::iterator` is not supposed to be used in the way you try to. It is a base class for other iterators classes, not an iterator class you may use directly.

Comment: Well, no extra work necessary when using iterator for set<int> for example, right?  I thought that because Vertex is my own defined class, I don't need to implement a new class just somehow use it differently.

Comment: It looks like you need `std::set<Vertex*>::iterator begin()` instead of `iterator<Vertex*> begin()`.

Comment: Bear in mind that your set contains pointers, so your less-than operator is irrelevant. The behaviour may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a two-step process involved here:

1. You need to give a type called `iterator` inside your `Vertex` class.
2. You need to then define `begin` and `end` to correctly use that iterator type.

Since you're hoping to iterate over the underlying `set` here, let's make the iterator type exported by your `Vertex` class be the iterator type that set provides. You can do that by writing

```
class Vertex{                                                   
public:
    int i, j; 
    std::set<Vertex*> adj; //references to adjacent vertices

    Vertex();
    ~Vertex();
    //end constructors

    /** must overload for set<Vertex> to function */
    const bool operator < (const Vertex &o) const;

    typedef std::set<Vertex*>::iterator iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

};//END class Vertex
```

Now, we can define `begin` and `end` as follows:

```
Vertex::iterator Vertex::begin() {
    return adj.begin();
}
Vertex::iterator Vertex::end() {
    return adj.end();
}
```

This now lets you write things like

```
Vertex v = /* ... */;
for (Vertex::iterator itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr) {
    /* ... */
}
```

or

```
Vertex v = /* ... */
for (auto& adj: v) {
   /* ... */
}
```

While we're at it, though, you can clean up this code quite a bit. For starters, you probably shouldn't make `i`, `j`, and `adj` public; that violates the principle of encapsulation. Make those data members private and provide member functions to access those values.

Another detail here is that you don't actually need to define `operator<` here. You need to define `operator<` if you will be directly storing objects of a given type inside of a `set` or as the keys in a `map`, but here you're storing *pointers* to `Vertex`es inside of the `set` and `map`. Therefore, unless you actually want to have `operator<` available for later, I wouldn't worry about defining `operator<`. You can just delete it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the type of iterator you're looking for is `std::set<Vertex*>::iterator` and to get the `begin` and `end` of the `set` you simply do `cur.adj.begin()` and `cur.adj.end()`.

Example:

```cpp
void func(Vertex* cur)
{
  if(cur == NULL)
    return;

  for(std::set<Vertex*>::iterator it = cur->adj.begin(); it != cur->adj.end(); ++it)
  {
    //Do something
  }
}
```

However, if you insist on implementing your code as `cur.begin()` and `cur.end()`, one way is to implement a `begin` and `end` function for your class like this.

```cpp
std::set<Vertex*>::iterator begin()
{
  return adj.begin();
}
std::set<Vertex*>::iterator end()
{
  return adj.end();
}
```